# How can i get filename for each upload file for a student data

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am trying to get file name for the uploaded files for a student. One student can have many courses, so I have an object containing all details. My file is base64 encoded.
        The student data object for one student looks like this:

```
    var studentdata ={
    data:
    [{
    name: 
    course:
    address:
    time:
    file: "this is base64 encoded data"
    },
    {
    name:
    course:
    address:
    time:
    file: "this is base64 encoded data"
    ]}
    }

    Here i want to add uploaded filaname for each file inside the object.
    I can't achieve this by getting the document.getElementById("fileinput").value. this will only give me name of first file.
    Is there any other way of doing this.
```

Comment: Read the examples on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: Looks like you got confused with my post, sorry about that. I am not using multiple in the input type.
 Only file is being uploaded for each object. I have to retrieve names of all files for all object before sending to header request.